# How to set startup page in IIS

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web-config, authorization

I have asp.net web application. I want to allow only Authenticated users to this application. Any anonymous users should get access denied error or should get redirected to login page.  So I added the “Authorization” element in config file to deny all anonymous users. I excluded `login.aspx` page so anonymous users can access it.

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
         <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="login.aspx">
         <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
         </system.web>
   </location>
```

**NOTE**: This application use Azure AD for authentication thats why you see authetication mode="None". When user access login page it just redirect user to Azure site for authentication. And this authentication piece is working fine.

**Questions**

**1.** Consider my application is hosted in local IIS. Since only
    `login.aspx` is excluded from Authorization, if I type
    `http://localhost` I get access denied error. I have to explicitly
    type `http://localhost/login.aspx` to for login.  How do I change this
    so when I type `http://localhost` IIS will redirect to
    `http://localhost/login.aspx`  (I have already tried setting
    login.aspx as first page under default document in IIS)

**2.** What configuration I need to do, so if anonymous user try to
    access any resource under `http://localhost` he would get redirected
    to `http://localhost/login.aspx`  (This would also take care of 1st
    question)

Comment: Why not to show all users `login.aspx` to authorize?

Comment: well that was the question. user is not going to type www.mydomain.com/login.aspx...user is going to type only www.mydomain.com but if i have <authorization> that deny access to all anonymous users then it gives "access denied" error if i only type www.mydomain.com..

Comment: I get it, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Startup page name in Default document option like the below snagit:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Open IIS(Internet Information Service) Manager
2. Select “Default Document”
3. Add your file path to be homepage
   [image]

[image]