# How do I set a default content page on classic ASP?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

How do I set the default “index” landing page (also known as the default content page) on a Classic ASP file?

While setting up a simple first “Hello World” style classic ASP program locally, I remember how things are set up on the server where I will eventually migrate my work to.

On the server, in IIs, when I right-click on a Web Site, I can see properties.

[image]

And that brings up a tabbed dialog box where one of the tabs is “Documents”:

[image]

So, here, clearly I can set the name of the default content page.  Naturally, I want to set this up locally on my Windows 10 computer.

Now, even though I believe I have set up IIS on my side.  Things do now look the same on my side.  I have a windows 10 Operating System and so I expect things will look a bit differently according to style.  But I am hoping the functionality will be the same?  Will the functionality be the same?

On my end, on my Windows 10 computer, this is what I see when I right click on my web site?  I do not see anything about "Properties" which would bring up a dialog box where I can set the default content page.

[image]

I know, or at least I have read online is, that classic ASP is part of IIS.  So, here is the information I have gotten when I check the version of the ISS systems.

My local windows 10 iSS, help --> about menu selection produces this information:

[image]

On the server, the IIS has two options that come up in the Help menu that I find interesting.  They are "About Microsoft Management Console..." and "About Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager...

[image]

The information dialogs that come up when clicking on these are:

[image]

So, that is all I got thus far.  How to I proceed in setting up my ASP development capacity locally?

Comment: Significant changes were introduced in IIS 7 more than a decade ago, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-the-iis-manager-in-iis-7-and-iis-8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/ So if you want to make changes on IIS settings, study the configuration reference first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set startup page in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37585097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default page of my application in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605740)

Comment: The shortcut link `tinyurl.com/8y3cdwfy` appears to redirect to a broken image on the `lh3.googleusercontent.com` domain, so I am removing it from the question. Please add the image/link back again if you can recall what it was. It's worth noting that, per the warnings in the editor, shortlinks are not permitted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

IIS 10 on Windows 10 very similar to server edition.

Click on web site, on left panel use "Default Document"

[image]

Comment: Good work Zam.  Now I get to move forward :)

Comment: It's [been covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37585097) many times before.